# Dynamics Array in C++

Tags: c++

```
int len;
cin>>len;
string *test = new string[len];
```

This code working fine, but I want to know how to allocate dynamic memory without having to specify the length of the array like list in Python.Are there any solutions to do it?

Comment: Use a vector and you'll be a lot happier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ equivalent is the [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) template, which implements a dynamic array:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    assert( v.size() == 0 );

    v.push_back( 1 );
    v.push_back( 2 );
    v.push_back( 3 );

    assert( v.size() == 3 );

    for( std::size_t i = 0 i < v.size() ; ++i )
        std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
}
```

> 1
>   2
>   3

`std::vector` has many advantages:

- **Avoids to manage the memory of the dynamic array manually by the programmer**. Thats the big one I think.
- Like other Standard Library containers, has a lot of functionality (**Its batteries-included :P**), and is dessigned to work with standard library algorithms through iterators.
- **Its efficient**: As a dynamic array, the data of a vector is stored contiguously, so its a very cache-friendly container and in most situations performs far better than a linked list (`std::list`) due to its cache locallity.

Comment: `v.length()`? I guess you meant `v.size()` (and also `v.size() == 3` in the second `assert`).

Comment: Ooops, fixed. Thaks @Zeta

Comment: In case of using array, it there any solutions for that? I just want to know (not vector).

Comment: @MakaraPr You have to allocate a new array with the new size, copy the content from the old to the new, and put the element in its position in the new array, and finally delete the old array. Thats exactly what `std::vector` does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::vector` or `std::list`(or some other appropriate stl container) that will take care of the memory allocation for you.